# ASP.Net Namespace Folder Structure

Tags: asp.net, namespaces

HI all. I have a Web Application where I've defined my default namespace to be MyWebApp.  Now, in the root of my application I have a folder called \code where I store all of my C# code.  By default, any *.cs files that I create in this \code file get a namespace of MyWebApp\code.  I would prefer not to have the "\code" portion of the file hierarchy to make its way into my namespace hierarchy.

MyWebApp
    \code
       class1.cs    <-would like namespace to be MyWebApp
       \bizobjects
           customer.cs     <-would like namespace to be MyWebApp.bizobjects

I know I can modify every *.cs file I create but it's an annoyance.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end analysis it doesn't seem like there's an answer.  So for EVERY class I create I need to remember to go in a manually change the namespace.  I'll just send a feature request to MS.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to ASP.NET itself, but rather to how Visual Studio creates project items from new item templates. You could probably create a new item template for creating a class that generates a simpler namespace, however i think that's more effort than just manually cleaning up the namespace in a few files.

Comment: yikes, I don't think I'd want to try and write my own template. I agree with you.  I was hoping that maybe there was some trick like putting a config file into the subfolder with an option like "namespace segment name" or something.

Comment: nope, no config available. child namespaces belong in subfolders by convention. if you don't want a child namespace then put the cs file in the root (or rename the generated namespace manually)

Comment: Yea, I've heard that suggestion before too, thx.  It's just ironic how I end up having to do a little extra work because the tool screws up while trying to save me a little work!!!